# Not able to install anything and update on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, 14.10

Here are my content of /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release amd64 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main restricted
```

Please help me out.

Example error :

```
After this operation, 2,218 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  freeglut3 libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-3 fmit
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] yy
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main freeglut3 amd64 2.8.1-2 [73.4 kB]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main libfftw3-long3 amd64 3.3.4-1ubuntu1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe libfftw3-3 amd64 3.3.4-1ubuntu1
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe fmit amd64 0.99.2-1 [304 kB]
Fetched 377 kB in 10s (37.3 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fftw3/libfftw3-long3_3.3.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fftw3/libfftw3-3_3.3.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 has reached EOL. Please upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: It's given by my company.Can't change it.

Comment: You don't need to change it but upgrade it. Here's a [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) as to how to do that.

Comment: Hey it did trying what was mentioned in the link. But I am unable to update the release it says : nakulkumar@L-J2DHG32:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.10 is an obsolete version and if you want to use, update & install packages then you need to change its repository.

You can do this in following way:

Open Terminal & run:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Replace url `in.archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

save and close it.

Now run `sudo apt-get update`
and after then install any packages you want to install.

Comment: @nakulkumar If you want to understand why you need to do this, you can read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release#237118) answer.